# Generate Flash games from augmented reality marker

Tags: augmented-reality, flash-cs4

I would like to ask, is it possible to generate a flash games from AR marker?

Comment: you're only limited by your imagination =b

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Check out these These two:

http://www.metaio.com/products/web-sdk/

and

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/augmented_reality.html